# Projected attributes ALL vs Key only vs Include

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

While creating secondary Index in Dynamodb, there is label named **Projected attributed** with following list

```
 Projected attributed         
                     ALL
                     key only
                     Include
```

How all these affects(in terms of cost and performance) with LSI and GSI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

KEYS_ONLY – Each item in the index consists only of the table partition key and sort key values, plus the index key values. The KEYS_ONLY option results in the smallest possible secondary index.

INCLUDE – In addition to the attributes described in KEYS_ONLY, the secondary index will include other non-key attributes that you specify.

ALL – The secondary index includes all of the attributes from the source table. Because all of the table data is duplicated in the index, an ALL projection results in the largest possible secondary index.

Comment: do you know if projected attributes are updated when the same attribute in base table is updated?

Comment: in 'ALL' what would be the increase in cost be like?

Comment: @dashuser late but basically doubled

Comment: If working in Java, the construct for these looks like: `new Projection().withProjectionType("KEYS_ONLY")`